# How to reuse existing component in angularJS 1.6 from another controller?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, components, angularjs-1.6

We have a application built with `Ag-1.6` in `typescript` with component structure.
Now I have to re-use already created component in task which is a diffent component.
For eg: I have `TaskAddEditComponent` which i have to use in `CalendarEventController`

How can I import other component (`TaskAddEditComponent`) in `CalendarEventController` to use all the methods of  `TaskAddEditComponent`?

Comment: Use `factories / services` for common code re-use. Use `directives` for UI re-use. Please provide some code example when you need more advise. It's kind of vague at the moment.

Comment: Are you looking for require syntax -> https://toddmotto.com/on-init-require-object-syntax-angular-component/#using-require-as-an-object or do you want to reuse the controller functions only?